# Eclipse shape at bottom of the div using css

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to create an eclipse shape at the bottom of the `<div>`, I have tried below code but it is not giving the exact curve and corner bending, I want corners without bending, I attached the image with this, I want like attached image
[image]

```css
.curved-box-wrapper {
        background-color:blue;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 195px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: -4px 0px 8px 0px rgba(38,37,38,0.56);
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 120px 15%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 120px 15%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="curved-box-wrapper">

                            <p class="text-15 bold-600 no-margin-bottom">Clinic Patient Services</p>
                            <img src="{{asset('img/clinic-home-box.jpg')}}" alt="box"
                                 class="img-fluid box-img">
                            <p class="text-13 no-margin-bottom">
                                Provides help with selecting
                                or changing a provider and
                                questions about our clinic
                                programs or services.
                            </p>
                            <ul class="ul-no-space">
                                <li class="text-15 bold-600">Call:  (209) 468-6656</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get it exactly like that? With the solid white outline and box shadow and everything?

Comment: yes, i want exactly like picture above

Comment: above code i get result like this link picture https://ibb.co/268XXNR , but i want like above picture

Comment: Update your question with the code you're using in the snippet editor so it's easier for folks to tinker with what you got so far.

Comment: added snippet, thanks

Comment: May be you cause “elliptical borders” as shown here (do ctrl+f to find it) https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Comment: share your code!

Comment: For round corners you use border-radius:10px; for elliptical corners you divide it border-radius: 30px/10px;

Comment: i tried this all not working,

Comment: You could always create a transparent png image of the above and use it as a background image, then add text and other dynamic content above it..

Comment: i currently doing like that but i am looking for css solution